# How to Reduce or Decline Reads in Flutter with Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Flutter project with Firebase as the backend, and I've noticed that I'm incurring a lot of reads when fetching data from Firestore. This is affecting the cost and performance of my app. Is there a way to reduce or decline these reads?

Comment: The question is pretty broad. Reading data from Firebase is a normal part of the process of using the platform. Can you explain what a "lot of reads" means? The standard Free Firestore allows for p to 50K reads/day and then it's $0.0345 thereafter. If your app is reading more data than you expect, that's a coding issue which should be investigated. Without knowing the cause though, there isn't much that can be done here to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Combine Multiple Documents into One Document:**

Instead of fetching multiple documents, consider combining related data into a single document. You can separate each value with a specific label or separator to distinguish them. For example, you can use "*-${valueLabel}-*" as the separator. This way, you reduce the number of document reads when fetching related data.

Let's say you have a collection of "Products," and each product has various attributes like "name," "price," and "description." Instead of storing each attribute in a separate document, you can combine them into a single document, like this:

```
"query": "This is my title _-price-_this is my price(1200)_-desc-_this is my description"
```

Doing so will reduce your reads significantly! I've reduced my reads by almost 40 times.

**Remember**

The maximum number of characters you can store in each document is mandated, by Firebase, to 1 MB.

**How do I decode it?**

Simply use `split` to split the String (text) into different variables.

```
String query = "This is my title _-price-_this is my price(1200)_-desc-_this is my description";
 
           
String title = query.split(" _-price-_").first.trim(); 
String price = query.split(" _-price-_").last.split("_-desc-_").trim(); 
String description = query.split("_-desc-_").last.trim();
```

Also remember to add these Formatter in every TextField:

```
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'_-')),
],
```

This is to avoid having any accidents. Suppose the user added "*-desc-*" into their description text, then we would have problem because user wouldn't get what he desires!

Furthermore, please play around with codes to find your ideal version of this solution.

**How Do I user OrderBy Firebase Operation with this**

To do that please, `create` a different completely dedicated document for it. For Instance, you want to `orderBy` your product by `price`, create a document

```
"price": "this is your price(1200)"
"query": "This is my title _-price-_this is my price(1200)_-desc-_this is my description"
```

Use `price` document to run Firebase Operation `orderBy` and fetch only `query`.

***Reduced reads by 3 times*** in this particular case. In larger queries, you can save up the, i don't know, reads.